# Xamarin C# HttpClient upload Large Files

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, httpclient, large-file-upload

i'm trying to upload 10 Files ,100 Mb each one from a xamarin App.

the WebApi is a netcore Api,and the files are uploaded without any problems if i upload them one by one.

but when i try to upload the 10 files together as a Multipart Content using HttpClient, the app crashes with an exception ( Full Memory ).

i understood that the HttpClient is loading all the files in Memory which is not what i want to do.

Microsoft is recommanding Multipart File Upload for large files, but this is what i'm facing from the client side (Xamarin App )
is there a proper way to stream Large files using Multipart Content without loading the data in the Memory ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331036/multipartformdata-file-uploading-out-of-memory-exception

Comment: Here is a similar discussion .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378457/c-httpclient-file-upload-progress-when-uploading-multiple-file-as-multipartfo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: HttpClient, File upload progress when uploading multiple file as MultipartFormDataContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378457/c-httpclient-file-upload-progress-when-uploading-multiple-file-as-multipartfo)